# I delete entries from Chrome password manager, but Google Sync keeps reverting them

Tags: google-chrome, sync, passwords

I deleted a couple of entries from the password manager (Chrome->Settings->Manage Saved Passwords), because they have wrong/empty passwords/usernames.

This is the fifth or sixth time I'm making the same changes, deleting the same entries, and they keep popping back.

I have Chrome installed on 2 computers and on my Android phone, and the I'm signed into my Google Account from all devices, and sync is enabled. I suspect that sync is the culprit.

How do I make it accept my deletions?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's definitely the Google Sync. Try turning that off on all devices, clear the usernames and passwords and then turn sync on.

Comment: Clear the usernames and passwords on all devices, as in, repeat the same changes 3 times? Or just on a single device?